# How can I write a logarithmic expression using \underbrace?

Tags: text, underbrace

I am trying to write an expression using underbrace,in which i write a logarithmic expression,but it doesn't work as expected.

```latex
\[
 T(n) = 
 \begin{cases} 
      \Theta(\log_{10} n) &, n = $$\sum_{k=1}^{[\log_{10} n]} k*9^{k-1},n=\overline{k\underbrace{8..8}_\text{k={\log_{10} n}-1} 9}$$ \\
       \frac{100-x}{100} & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
      0 & 100\leq x 
   \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: @Mico Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @Mico Can you repost your previous solution?I think I managed to make the package work on my Latex distribution.

Comment: please consider Posting a graphical representation of what you want to Archive to give others a Goal and a clue in which direction development has to go. If in doubt a simple Photograph of your equation written manually on paper will do.

Comment: @derbender The thing is both Mico and egreg gave me accurate answers,however Mico's implementation didn't work for me  until I solved a problem with MiKTex and now I don't know which answer I should accept as solution,because both their answers were exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$` makes no sense in that context (and should never be used in LaTeX).

Here's a solution with no additional package, apart from `amsmath`.

I define a special `cases`-like environment with display style in each entry; for this I increase the separation between formula and description, so to get it less crowded.

For the subscript to the underbrace I define a special “zero width” command.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{mathcases}
 {%
  \left\{
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \everymath{\displaystyle}%
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{\qquad}l@{}}%
 }
 {\end{array}\right.}
\newcommand{\zwsub}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}

\begin{document}

\[
T(n) = 
\begin{mathcases}
\Theta(\log_{10} n) & 
  n = \sum_{k=1}^{[\log_{10} n]} k*9^{k-1},
  n = \overline{k\underbrace{8\dots 8}_{\zwsub{k=[\log_{10} n]-1}} 9} \\
\frac{100-x}{100} & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\[3ex]
0 & 100\leq x 
\end{mathcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left `*`, but it should probably be `\cdot` (no mathematician uses the asterisk for multiplication). Also `[...]` should possibly be replaced by `\lfloor...\rfloor`, to use a more current notation for the greatest integer function.

Comment: @egred Thanks for taking your time to properly solve my problem and explain some things to me.P.S:I am not an inspiring mathematician :),so I didn't know that regarding multiplication.